# R item combinations

Tags: r, count, combinations

I'm using R and want to find the most common pairs between consumers.

```
consumer=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5)
items=c("apple","banana","carrot","date","eggplant","apple","banana","fig","grape","apple","banana","apple","carrot","date","eggplant","apple")
shoppinglists <- data.frame(consumer,items)
```

Is there a way to see that "apple"+"banana" appears on three lists (consumers 1,2 and 3) and "apple"+"carrot" appears on two lists (consumers 1 and 4)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see that information here:

```
tbl <- table(shoppinglists)
t(tbl) %*% tbl
#          items
#items      apple banana carrot date eggplant fig grape
#  apple        5      3      2    2        2   1     1
#  banana       3      3      1    1        1   1     1
#  carrot       2      1      2    2        2   0     0
#  date         2      1      2    2        2   0     0
#  eggplant     2      1      2    2        2   0     0
#  fig          1      1      0    0        0   1     1
#  grape        1      1      0    0        0   1     1
```

To see that apple pairs up with banana 3 times and carrot 2 times, look in the first row or the down  the first column.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Unfortunately the data I'm actually using has about 5,000 different items making it impossible to examine the table. Would you have any ideas on how to get around that problem?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're looking to do, and what it is you want to see,  but you could output a single column:  `tbl <- t(tbl) %*% tbl; tbl[, "apple"]`

Comment: I figured it out: 
   `tbl <- table(shoppinglists);  tbl <- t(tbl) %*% tbl`
followed by:
    `tbl[lower.tri(tbl, diag=TRUE)]<-0;
    itemlist <- data.frame(row = rep(rownames(tbl), length(rownames(tbl))), col = rep(colnames(tbl), each = length(rownames(tbl))), x = as.vector(tbl)) `