# R item combinations group of 3

Tags: r, count, combinations

Here is a solution for finding [pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467871/r-item-combinations), but what about triples?

If I have:

```
consumer=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5)
items=c("apple","banana","carrot","date","eggplant","apple","banana",
        "fig","grape","apple","banana","apple","carrot","date",
        "eggplant","apple")
shoppinglists <- data.frame(consumer,items)
table(shoppinglists)
```

Is there an easy way to find the most combinations of triples? For example, the triples "carrots"+"date"+"eggplant", "apple"+"carrots"+"date", "apple"+"carrots"+"eggplant", and "apple"+"date"+"eggplant" each appear on two lists (consumers 1 and 4).

You can see that there are many tied for second place with one appearance: A+B+C, A+B+D, A+B+E, B+C+D, B+C+E (consumer 1); A+B+F, A+B+G (consumer 2).

Comment: I'm looking to only return cases of triples and have the result give me a list of the triples and how many times they each appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer with `data.table` that will extend to quadruples, etc. pretty easily:

```
library(data.table); setDT(shoppinglists)

#exclude if consumer didn't buy 3 goods
shoppinglists[ , if (.N >= 3L) 
  .(triplet =
      #get the combinations 3 at a time;
      #  keep them as a list (simplify=FALSE)
      #  for easy post-manipulation with sapply
      sapply(combn(items, 3L, simplify = FALSE),
             #**should be a better way...**
             paste, collapse = ",")), 
  by = consumer
  #now count the total frequency of each triplet
  ][ , .N, by = triplet
     #and sort to see the most frequent
     ][order(-N)]
#                    triplet N
#  1:      apple,carrot,date 2
#  2:  apple,carrot,eggplant 2
#  3:    apple,date,eggplant 2
#  4:   carrot,date,eggplant 2
#  5:    apple,banana,carrot 1
#  6:      apple,banana,date 1
#  7:  apple,banana,eggplant 1
#  8:     banana,carrot,date 1
#  9: banana,carrot,eggplant 1
# 10:   banana,date,eggplant 1
# 11:       apple,banana,fig 1
# 12:     apple,banana,grape 1
# 13:        apple,fig,grape 1
# 14:       banana,fig,grape 1
```

For doubles, we can use  `combn(value, 2L)`; for quadruples, `combn(value, 4L)`, etc.

Replace `order(-N)` with `N == max(N)` to exclude all but the most frequent.

I wish we didn't have to `paste`-`collapse` this -- I expected `list()` to work, but counting `by` a `list` column apparently doesn't work.

Comment: here is a [great tutorial for data.table](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-data-table-r-tutorial-by-datacamp-intro-to-dti-j-by/) if anyone is like me and is trying to understand how this answer works!

Comment: @gregorio099 even better is the [list of tutorials](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) from GitHub

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`arules`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html) package.  It's worth exploring if you're doing a lot of this work, as it:

> Provides the infrastructure for representing, manipulating and
>   analyzing transaction data and patterns (frequent itemsets and
>   association rules). Also provides interfaces to C implementations of
>   the association mining algorithms Apriori and Eclat by C. Borgelt.

Here is a solution using the eclat algorithm:

```
# Set up the object you'll pass to eclat:
tbl <- table(shoppinglists)
itemList <- matrix(tbl)
dim(itemList) <- dim(tbl)
colnames(itemList) <- colnames(tbl)
```

Now, you can use `eclat`.  There is a `support` argument for specifying the minimum support needed for an itemset to be considered frequent. In this case, you want everything regardless of frequency, so you can set `support` to 0.  You'll get a warning that setting it to 0 could result in running out of memory.

```
library(arules)
d <- eclat(itemList, parameter = list(minlen = 3, maxlen = 3, support = 0))
```

You can construct the data.frame you want using data contained in `d`.  Generate the number of transactions per itemset by multiplying support (`quality(d)`) by the total number of transactions  (`info(d)$ntransactions`):

```
d2 <- data.frame(items = labels(d), quality(d) * info(d)$ntransactions)
names(d2)[2] <- "N" # to rename from "support" to "N"
d2
#                      items N
#1         {apple,fig,grape} 1
#2        {banana,fig,grape} 1
#3      {apple,banana,grape} 1
#4        {apple,banana,fig} 1
#5     {apple,date,eggplant} 2
#6    {banana,date,eggplant} 1
#7    {carrot,date,eggplant} 2
#8   {apple,carrot,eggplant} 2
#9  {banana,carrot,eggplant} 1
#10  {apple,banana,eggplant} 1
#11      {apple,carrot,date} 2
#12     {banana,carrot,date} 1
#13      {apple,banana,date} 1
#14    {apple,banana,carrot} 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer- this is really interesting, too. When I try this with the shoppinglists example I get the same results as you, but when I use a much bigger list the eclat function only writes/outputs two triplets. Do you know what might be going on?

Comment: @gregorio099 Let me know if the edit about setting the `support` parameter solves the issue.